# More than one table in SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am facing problem in creating more than one tables in sqllite database in android.
Here is my code

```
   public class DataHelper {
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "example.db";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";
   private static final String SETTING_TABLE="setting";

   private Context context;
   private SQLiteDatabase db;

   private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
   private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + 
       "(name) values (?)";
   private static final String INSERTSETTING = "insert into " + SETTING_TABLE +
       "(name) values (?)";

   public DataHelper(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
      this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
      this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERTSETTING);
   }

   public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
      return this.db;
   }

   public long insert(String name) {
      this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
      return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
   }   
   private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
      OpenHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }
      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
              " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SETTING_TABLE + 
              " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
      }
      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
      {
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
         onCreate(db);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? It1s possible to create multiple Tables on SQLite.

Comment: Display the error(s) you receive....

Comment: It is working fine within one table when I want to add second table than it is giving me error(table not exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the value of DATABASE_VERSION, otherwise onUpgrade won't get called.

I notice you don't drop the SETTING_TABLE in onUpgade, and you're losing the first insert statement at the top of your code, as you replace INSERT with INSERTSETTING.